# Getting the OnClick event when enter is pressed (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code (inherited from someone):

```
<div class="feedback">&nbsp;</div>
   <form onsubmit="return false" autocomplete="off">
      Enter your guess: 
      <input type="text" size="48" id="guessedword"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Guess!" id="guessbutton"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

Now, I want to do something when the "Guess!" button is pressed, but I don't want the page to change (i.e. I don't want the form submitted). That's why the onsubmit is mapped to `"return false"`. I also have the following JQuery:

```
$("#guessbutton").bind("click", onGuess);
```

The thing is, this works great in Firefox and Chrome. The only problem is IE. The guess button  works correctly, the only problem is that when pressing `Enter` in the `text` field, the button isn't pressed, or at least the onClick behavior is never called. In Firefox and Chrome, it works great.

Is there any way to make this work the way I want it? Or am I going about this whole thing the wrong way? (I'm new to HTML, so I'm not even sure this is the right way to do things).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write :

```
<form onsubmit="onGuesS(); return false;" autocomplete="off">
```

This will not redirect enter to onclick, but in all the three browsers, Enter is equivalent to submitting the form.. so u write ur login in onSubmit and the return false that the page does not get submitted again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onkeypress() event and handle enter key press. Dont use type="submit". Use type="button" instead. If you dont submit form to the server dont use it at all. Remove form tag from code.

```
<div class="feedback">&nbsp;</div>
      Enter your guess: 
      <input type="text" size="48" id="guessedword"/>
      <input type="button" value="Guess!" id="guessbutton"/>
</div>

document.onkeypress = function(){
   //your handling code here. keyKode of Enter key = 13
}
```